# Why does $\lVert u\rVert_{W^{k+2,p}}\leq C\lVert\Delta u\rVert_{W^{k,p}}$ imply injectivity of $\Delta$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with nontrivial boundary. I try to prove that for each nonnegative integer $k$ and every $p>1$, the $g$-Laplacian
$$\Delta:W_0^{k+2,p}(M)\to W^{k,p}(M)$$
is injective. $W_0^{k+2,p}(M)$ is the collection of functions in the Sobolev space $W^{k+2,p}(M)$ that vanish on $\partial M$.

If I can find a constant $C$ so that for each $u\in W_0^{k+2,p}(M)$,
$$\lVert u\rVert_{W^{k+2,p}}\ \ \leq C\lVert\Delta u\rVert_{W^{k,p}}\ ,\tag{$*$}$$
then is there anything I can say to reach injectivity of $\Delta$? A book says that $(*)$ implies injectivity, but I don't see how. Can we suppose $\Delta u=\Delta v$ and deduce $u=v$? In this case, the norm of $u$ is of the same order as that of $v$, that is, they are both bounded above by $C\lVert\Delta u\rVert=C\lVert\Delta v\rVert$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By linearity of the Laplace operator $\Delta$

$$\|u-v\|\leq C\|\Delta(u-v)\|=C\|\Delta u-\Delta v\|=C\|0\|=0$$
and by positive definiteness of the norm this implies $u-v=0\iff u=v$ (a.e).